# a question about kernelized locality preserving projections

Tags: machine-learning, spectral-method

kernel LPP is of form:
$$\min_{\alpha} \  \alpha^{T}KLK\alpha
\\
s.t. \  \alpha^{T}KDK\alpha = 1$$
and it eventually results in solving generalized eigenvalue problem below:
$$KLK \alpha= \lambda KDK \alpha$$
It has same eigenvalues as:
$$Ly=\lambda Dy$$
so here I solve the above eigen system knowing that:
$$y=K \alpha$$
Notice the objective value of original kernel LPP is:
$$\alpha^{T}KLK\alpha=\lambda\alpha^{T}KDK\alpha=\lambda y^{T}Dy$$
Does it mean that changing K won't affect the objective value of KLPP? Because here I get eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $y$ without using K.

Any answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The minimum of the objective function is the minimal eigenvalue of the generalized eigenproblem $Ly = \lambda Dy$, regardless of $K$, at least as long as $K$ has full column rank.